# Show that $\liminf$ of the intersection of convex subsets is convex

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $\{A_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ sequence of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the set given by
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{m \to + \infty} A_m := \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=k}^{\infty} A_m
\end{align*}
is convex.

We have already established that the union of a convex set is also convex. However, the notation of the given problem completely outsmarts me. Any ideas?

Comment: union of convex sets are not convex in general. Did you mean to write ``intersection'' ?

Comment: @daw Oops yeah sorry I am fixing it.

Comment: Let $p,q\in\lim\inf A_m.$ Then   $\{m:p\in A_m\}$ and $\{m:q\in A_m\}$ are finite. So for some $m$, both $p$ and $q$ belong to the convex set $A_m.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you just need to recp what the definition of $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty$ and $\bigcap\limits_{m=k}^\infty$ means.

A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is convex if, given any two points in the subset, the subset contains the whole line segment that joins them.

So take to arbitrary points $$a_1, a_2 \in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=k}^{\infty} A_m$$ and show that the line segment that joins them is also included.

For notation puposes let's define $$B_k = \bigcap_{m=k}^{\infty} A_m$$

We have $$a_1, a_2 \in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k$$ by definition of the union that's the case if $a_i \in B_k$ for some $1 \le k < \infty$

So we have something like $a_1 \in B_{k_1}, a_2 \in B_{k_2}$

But because the $B_k$ are a decreasing sequence of sets $a_1$ and $a_2$ are included in the bigger one, wlog let this be $B_{k_1}$.

So we have: $a_1,a_2 \in B_{k_1}$

And now it holds $$B_{k_1} = \bigcap_{m=k_1}^{\infty} A_m$$ and by definition of the intersection we now have $a_1,a_2 \in A_m$ for $k_1 \le m < +\infty$

But each $A_m$ is convex by assumption so it follows, that the joint line between is also in each $A_m, k_1 \le m < +\infty$.

But when the joint line is in each $A_m, k_1 \le m < +\infty$ so it is in $$B_{k_1} = \bigcap_{m=k_1}^{\infty} A_m$$ and in $$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k = \liminf_{m \to + \infty} A_m$$

Hence, $\liminf\limits_{m \to + \infty} A_m$ is convex.

Comment: Very elegant and well written!